# Titanium (Node.js) require() vs Global

Tags: javascript, node.js, titanium, require, commonjs

I'm unsure if any of the following is considered a better practice.

**Environment:**
Appcelerator Titanium/Alloy, which is a framework to make native apps. It uses javascript as source, comparable to node.js (more like CommonJS).

**Case 1:**

Many files where i use:

```
var localInstance = require('main/module/sub/foobar')({ initialize: true});
```

**Case 2:**

A main file where I would make a global:

```
Globalnamespace.foobar = require('main/module/sub/foobar');
```

And in other files:

```
var localInstanceWhichINeed = Globalnamespace.foobar({initialize: false});
```

The point is that the module is not needed everywhere, and putting it in global namespace might take unnecessary memory. Every `foobar` module needs to be instantiated in every file, so there is no global instance (only a module to make an instance).

I'm talking about mobile device memory and im trying to cut down on it. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the best person to respond to this. However, I have investigated the same question and therefore have some insight that may help you ;-)

The way CommonJS modules work is that they are loaded the first time you refer to them. So a subsequent referral is at a very low cost. Therefore, I would say that it is more a question about "flavour". Personally, I tend to use the first approach that you mention, ie. something like this:

```
var UiHelper = require('ui/helper);
  :
  :
UiHelper.showListBox(.....);
```

So back to your question - I don't think there is a penalty of using one or the other. It is more about how you want to structure your code ;-)

/John

Comment: alright that makes sense, if `require()` already uses a friendly approach to prevent useless reloading then I will go with that option. I guess it's still a micro-optimization because `case 2` would load it on places where you might not need it

Comment: I agree on that - which is why I use the other approach as shown (like your case 1) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically concerning namespace usage and Titanium: I wouldn't recommend it. The namespaces go out of scope so easily. Even when you tie them to Ti.App (not a good idea either).

And CommonJS (especially in the latest versions of Titanium) is really good at not reloading things it has loaded before.

If you're worried about memory, make sure all of your views and windows are being destroyed when you're done with them. That's the #1 thing in Titanuim.

Comment: +1 As well, wouldve marked as best answer if you were the first. I've yet to define a structure for easily destroying views and controllers (im using `Alloy` MVC) since I hear so much about the lousy garbage collection as long as you dont actively help it yourself.

Comment: I don't use alloy, but the general practice is to create an off-screen window, move all views to it and delete the window. Doesn't work as well in Android as the windows like to show up on screen, but Android is better at the garbage collection...